# I am having problems adding domain accounts to local groups

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

When adding domain accounts to local groups in my newly created domain, the domain account displays the sid next to the same (for example *DOMAIN\ACCOUNT (s-1-5-21-XXXXXXX)*)

Can someone give me some ideas on how to correct this situation?

Additional info:

I have noticed that all accounts (local and domain) are showing the SID along with the account name.

I have tried to remove the member computer from the domain and rejoined it.  This did not fix the problem.

I  can authenticate with these accounts to the domain.

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs on the DC regarding DNS?

Comment: You mention that the SID is displayed - is that all that is wrong?  Are the domain accounts added OK?

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually having a problem?  Or is it just that you don't want to see the SIDs alongside the usernames.  Honestly as long as you're not seeing ONLY a SID it should be ok, and might just be a visual issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that when the domain account no longer exists or the computer cannot connect to the domain controller.

Comment: the domain account still exists and the member computer does have connectivity to the domain (I can authenticate to the domain on the member computer).

Answer (score 0):

Are the names of the accounts the same as the name of an account on the directory? So have you a domain user called james and a local user called james

James

Comment: No, not necessarily. This is happening on all the accounts (built-in, local, and domain).